# Unable to add jQuery UI Datepicker widgets to MVC solution

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to add date time picker controls in my MVC project. I installed jQuery UI(combined library) in my solution but the jquery datepicker.js files are not added to scripts so i tried to install jQuery UI Widgets:Datepicker but this throws the error

Updating 'jQuery 1.8.3' to 'jQuery 1.4.4' failed. Unable to find versions of 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax, Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation' that are compatible with 'jQuery 1.4.4'.

The version of jQuery UI istalled my solution is 1.8.9. 
All I need is to add couple of datepicker controls and other input controls in my View.I may have to add these controls in multiple views for create/edit etc. Since am a beginner to both MVC and jQuery, I am stuck and not able to proceed.
Please help me with your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `jquery-ui.js` and the matching `.css` file to your page, you can load a new datepicker by simply doing:

```
$("#myid").datepicker();
```

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I have tried this and added my control like this <input type="date" id="startdatepicker" />. But the textbox is not popping datepicker on click of textbox

Comment: No. It doesnt work. Hence i thought i may have to add jquery ui datepicker widget too. But unfortunately am not able to install it

Comment: You need to install the version compatible with your jQuery.